# How can I `await` on an Rx Observable to have a specific value?

Tags: javascript, rxjs, observable

I'd like to await an observable to have a define value before moving forward.

I tried the follwoing, but it is not working, even if `myObservable$` is instantiated with a value

`await lastValueFrom(this.myObservable$.pipe(filter((event) => (event == 'something' ? true : false))))`

### Context

In angular, while loading the app inside an iFrame, I need a token that may exists locally or being set by the parent.

If this is set by the parent, I would like my guard to await till the token has been value.

### Workaround

I've create an observable only for this purpose, so I could use the `await lastValueFrom(this.myObservable$)` and this is working, but I'm just wondering if it was possible to await a specific value.

Comment: `BehaviourSubject` would probably help you, but you can all use `toPromise()` and use `await` as you wanted

Comment: `toPromise()` seems to be deprecated, for what I read.  Already tried the `BehaviourSubject` but didn't seems to have worked, or at least I don't know how

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order for `lastValueFrom` to emit anything, its observable source must complete (*otherwise, there is no "last" value*).

You can force it to complete by using `take(1)` after your filter condiation:

```js
await lastValueFrom(this.myObservable$.pipe(
    filter(event => event === 'something'),
    take(1)
));
```

Comment: I would have liked to wait for a specific value, and `take(1)` will only take the actual value, that said, for my specific case it work like a charm, Also read on the [RxJS documentation](https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/operators/filtering/take) and that's what they say. "For example, a stream of user token updates, or a route guard based on a stream in an Angular application.", so thx a lot :)

Comment: I’m not sure what you mean between “specific value” and “actual value”. The combination of `filter` and `take(1)` does allow you to wait for a specific value. You can adjust the filter criteria to only allow a specific value through.

Comment: All clear, I misread the documentation. Thx a lot !

Answer (score 0):

Sure, use [takeWhile](https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/operators/filtering/takewhile).

```
await lastValueFrom(this.myObservable$.pipe(takeWhile(val => val != 5, true)))
```

Comment: Stupid question, but did you have tested it ? Because I do try but it wont never emit any value.